# Prevent recursion on replacing elements

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

at first: No, this is not a duplicate. I know that there are some possibilities to search for elements in a HTML-page, but this is not really my problem.

I will outline my problem:

My PHP-code is for reasons I can not change called 2-3 times on every page-rendering.

My code crawls the html-content for specific words and replaces them with a link.

To archive this I am using https://github.com/sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser .

This is my source:

```
foreach ( $dom->find( 'text' ) as $element ) {
//$config['exclusions'] is an array like ['a', 'img']
                if ( !in_array( $element->parent()->tag, $config[ 'exclusions' ] ) ) {
                    foreach ( $markers as $marker ) {
                        $text    = $marker[ 'text' ];
                        $url     = $marker[ 'url' ];
                        $tip     = strip_tags( $marker[ 'excerpt' ] );
                        $tooltip = ( $tooltip ? "data-uk-tooltip title='$tip'" : "" );
                        $tmpval  = "tmpval-$i";

                        $element->innertext = preg_replace(
                            '/\b' . preg_quote( $text, "/" ) . '\b/i',
                            "<a href='$url' $hrefclass target='$target' $tmpval>\$0</a>",
                            $element->innertext,
                            1
                        );


                        $element->innertext = str_replace( $tmpval, $tooltip, $element->innertext );
                        $i++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

The problem is: If the `$tooltip` contains a word that matches a marker, this word is being replaced. So the result is `<a href='foo.html' target='_self' data-uk-tooltip title='<a href='bar.html'...'>\$0</a>` which destroys the markup of the page.

So my question: How can I prevent this?

Comment: Sort the `$markers` by length descending, and then build a pattern like `implode("|", $markers)` (remember to escape the items with `preg_quote` with `arrapy_map`) and then run the `preg_replace_callback` passing the `$markers` into the anonymous function where you will be able to perform a replacement of the current non-overlapping occurrence of the text.

Answer (score 1):

Use lookbehind:

```
$element->innertext = preg_replace(
    '(?<!\w=['"])\b' . preg_quote( $text, "/" ) . '\b/ig',
    "<a href='$url' $hrefclass target='$target' $tmpval>\$0</a>",
    $element->innertext,
    1
);
```

Comment: Hello and thank you. Here I get  > lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 13 .

Comment: Sorry. Updated my answer.